# Java - apache commons exec, abnormal execution behaviour

Tags: java, apache, command-line, command-prompt

I am running this command with apache commons exec

```
C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /C start ".\\test" /D ".\\test1" .\\test1\\ldecod.exe -p InputFile=\"test.h264\" -p OutputFile="test.yuv"
```

the command runs normally through command prompt i.e. starts ldecod.exe and decodes test.h264, but when running the same command through apache commons exec it just opens the folder "test1"

What's going on here?

edit: using the following code

```
String cmd = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /C start \".\\test\" /D \".\\test1\" .\\test1\\ldecod.exe -p InputFile=\"test.h264\" -p OutputFile=\"test.yuv\"";
CommandLine commandline = CommandLine.parse(cmd);
DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
exec.execute(commandline);
```

Comment: Nobody could possible tell what is going on here from this description. You need to provide some code and some actual output of your code.

Comment: @dcsohl i am not sure what i can include, i'm just following the example of executing a command from their doc

Comment: Don't say `(same string as above)` - I want to see what you are actually doing. Include the string. Also, how do you know "it just opens the folder 'test1'"?

Comment: @dcsohl that is what happens when i run this code, it opens "test1" in a new window (through windows explorer)

Comment: And what's it supposed to do? What's all the `/C` and `/D`? I get the actual executable, `.\\test1\\ldecod.exe -p ...` but what's with the stuff before that? Why aren't you just running `.\\test1\\ldecod.exe -p ...`?

Comment: @dcsohl I want to use the command `start` so that it will open a new window for ldecod.exe, `/D` is an option for `start` that lets me define the starting directory e.g. the same as `cd .\\test1 ldecod.exe -p...` I want to do this because ldecod.exe creates log file at the directory where it was called (not where the exe is).  Since `start` is a windows command it can only be used with `cmd /C` similar to `cd`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the /b argument to the windows start command. This will run the your command without starting a new command prompt.
From the [docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297.aspx):

> /b - Starts an application without opening a new Command Prompt window. CTRL+C handling is ignored unless the application enables CTRL+C processing. Use CTRL+BREAK to interrupt the application.

The way you are running it, start is spawning a new process. I suspsect that ldecod.exe is running but the start command (and your program) does not terminate  till you close the command prompt.